# A Riemannian metric on the special orthogonal group

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, lie-groups

I have an issue with an exercise that is concerned with a Riemannian metric on the special orthogonal group.

[image]

My problem lies with a). I am working with the following definitions

[image]

[image]

I have managed to show that $g$ is an inner product on each tangent space $T_B \text{SO}(n)$.

Now let $\text{Sym(T SO(n))}$ denote the bundle whose fiber at $B \in \text{SO(n)}$ consists of all symmetric bilinear forms $T_B \text{SO}(n) \times T_B \text{SO}(n) \to \mathbb{R}$.

Now I need to show that $g$ is a section of $\text{Sym(TSO(n))}$. In order for this to be true I have to show that $g$ is smooth in the sense that the map

$$
H: \text{SO(n)} \to \text{Sym(T SO(n))}, 
B \mapsto ((X_B,Y_B) \mapsto g_B(X_B,Y_B)=\text{tr}(X_B^T Y_B))
$$

is smooth. For this, I consider charts $(\varphi, U)$ of $\text{SO(n)}$ and $(\psi,V)$ of $\text{Sym(T SO(n))}$. I need to show that $\psi \circ H \circ \varphi^{-1}$ is smooth. But now I'm a bit at a loss about how to do this.

Comment: $SO(n)$ is an embedded submanifold of $GL(n, \mathbb R)$. Can you use that?